# Why manage.py can't see the __init__ file?

Tags: python, flask

I'm just making a blog app with this structure:

```
blog/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    manage.py
    config.py
    tests.py
    __pycache__
    ...
```

When dev server is running I run also `manage.py`:

```
 import unittest, sys
 from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
 from blog import create_app
```

what I don't understand is why I'm getting error on the third line `no module named blog`. Almost as if it's not picking up on `__init__.py` being present.

**Edit:**

```
 import unittest, sys
 from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
 from . import create_app
```

structure:

```
├── blog
│   ├── client
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests
│   └── venv
```

output from `manage.py`:

```
(venv) mark@python:~/blog$ python manage.py test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import create_app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**Another edit:**

I went for another structure:

```
── my_blog
│   ├── project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── main_test.py
│   └── venv
│       ├── bin
│       ├── lib
│       └── pyvenv.cfg


mark@python:~/my_blog/tests$ python3 main_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from project.main import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Comment: Yes, that's why `__init__.py` is there. The import fails.

Comment: Yes sorry I misunderstood. I think there is some kind of resolution error here, as the `blog` module may not be in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @00  I've tried that already. I got error about using relative import.

Comment: @00 Edit added.

Comment: For `from blog import create_app` to work, the *parent* directory of `blog` must be among the directories in the search path, `sys.path`. When you run program `manage.py`, the directory containing it, `blog` in this case, is added to `sys.path`, but that is *not* the same thing. But this allows you to do `from . import create_app` if `create_app.py` is in the same directory.

Comment: @00 No. You would need the *parent* directory of `blog` to be in your `PYTHONPATH` to reference a package named `blog.manage`

Comment: @Booboo  I added another edit. More puzzled now.

Comment: The previous comments already provide excellent insight. I made a python package + documentation as an online reference to help me make fewer import mistakes. Maybe it'll be useful. https://github.com/ankur-gupta/rain

Answer (score 0):

Adding parent directory to `PYTHONPATH` solved the problem. Thank you all for pointers.